# Eclipse PDT - Dynamic syntax highlighting

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

Am looking for an eclipse plugin to allow for dynamic syntax highlighting similar to that in Nusphere PhpEd.

So when I click onto html it dims out the other languages inside the file (js, css, php etc.)

Cheers